# Is is OK to use setTimeout to avoid NG0100 when doing patchValue to a reactive form in afterViewInit?

Tags: angular, settimeout, angular-reactive-forms, patchvalue

I have a parent - child component with reactive forms. Child propagates changes to parent via ControlValueAccessor.

I need to pass initial value via the template with @Input annotated variable (in the real app I want to pass the initial value from ngFor hence the @Input).

I can't set the passed in initial value during formGroup creation in the child constructor because the @Input ed value is not available yet.

I also can't set it in ngOnInit for the same reason.

In afterViewInit I can do it, and it's working, BUT only if I wrap the patchValue call inside a setTimeout. Otherwise [NG0100](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100): Expression has changed after it was checked error is thrown:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('ngAfterViewInit called');
  // if I omit setTimeout then NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
  // is it OK for using setTimeout for this?
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.formGroup.patchValue({
      firstName: this.initialFirstName,
    });
  }, 0);
}
```

Is it OK to use setTimeout to avoid the error, is it reliable? Is there a better solution?

The whole thing is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rohjor?file=src/app/name-input/name-input.component.ts

Comment: No, usually it is not OK to use setTimeout in order to twist the way change detection works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have worked inside `ngOnInit`, but the problem is that the change handler of your control value accessor is not yet registered. You can do it inside `registerOnChange` handler like this:

```js
public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  console.log('registerOnChange called');
  this.onChange = fn;

  this.setUpDefaultValues();
}

private setUpDefaultValues(): void {
  this.formGroup.patchValue({
    firstName: this.initialFirstName,
  });
}
```

This way, when your subscribe handler inside the `ngOnInit` method is hit, the `this.onChange` will have *the correct value* (the one that was registered through the control value accessor).

I recommend you to stop giving default values to these control value accessor handlers because this way, you will actually get more meaningful errors (like `Error: this.onChange is not a function`) that should trigger this alarm for you and let you know that you try to use the handler before it was registered:

```js
private onChange?: (value: any | null) => void;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, and for the comment about default value for onChange / onTouched.